# How does Islam interpret the creation of the universe and is it compatible with the Big Bang Theory?

Tags: creation, universe

My colleagues and I often discuss about **creation of universe**, our solar system which is, in scientific theories, explained by **Big Bang Theory**.

**My questions are:**

- Was this universe, specially our solar system, created according to the Big Bang Theory?
- Does Quran and Ahadiths support this theory or tell us something else
  about how Allah almighty created this universe??

Answer (score 9):

walaikum assalam

First of all [Big Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) is just a theory and might be proven wrong, or incomplete one day, so basically we don't know if this theory is 100% true.

I think quran supports this theory as I understand, see this verse:

> Have those who disbelieved not considered that the heavens and the earth were a joined entity, and We separated them and made from water every living thing? Then will they not believe? [[21:30](http://quran.com/21/30)]

Quoting from the Tafseer of Tabatabai ([translation](http://www.holyquran.net/cgi-bin/almizan.pl?ch=21&vr=30&sp=10&sv=0)):

> The repetition of separation of particles and atoms and what we see in the air and atmosphere guides us to a stage where the skies and earth were all one entity and Allah has separated them[...]

Edit:

From the comments, it seems that some scholars have different explanations of the above verse so it might be not compatible after all.

Comment: In Ahadeeth but we are told how the universe began and how Quran is interpreted to this result; as far as I have seen the answer is no, Big Bang was not the beginning of this universe, but Almizan anyway is far more authentic than my ideas :)

Comment: @awari do you have this hadeeth that the universe didn't start with big bang. Because I have the opposite!

Comment: @owari, Well, I have also heard a variation of BBT that universe has gone under many cycles of contraction and expansion each starting by and ending in a recurring big bang. If true, that means the substance of the universe has always been there, and this conforms to the belief of many muslim meta-physicians who argue that the universe is eternal and ever-lasting.

Comment: @infatuated, and you surely have seen the unbelievable consequences of what they think about contraction, the law of increase of entropy should reverse so that as time passes by entropy always decreases, disorder changes into order and etc., these are not science but science-fiction.

Comment: Although even through expansion of universe and the universe with all its internal orders (*the subject of different branches of science*) being the result of an explosion itself is a contradiction to the 2nd law, unless one assumes an intelligence who controls the whole thing. Some scholars assume such and say the existence of big bang goes well with the existence of God, but I was trying to say big bang was not the scenario for this universe, nor was the cycles of expansion-contraction.

Comment: Actually big bang is not even really scientifically proved, there are some evidences for it like the red-shift Doppler effect together with the existence of the cosmic background radiation, but also some problems with it. Thus no need for Islamic scholar to justify it, Islam has its own view of the start of the creation.

Comment: @awari do you have another tafseer for the ayah above? if so please enlighten me. I clearly said that quran doesn't support **everything** in the theory, but at least the part that the universe started with an expansion.

Comment: @Mhmd, sorry for being late, I very rarely come here, but anyway please see if this Hadeeth helps: "فَقَالَ لَهُ الشَّامِيُّ يَا أَبَا جَعْفَرٍ قَوْلُ اللَّهِ تَعَالَى- أَ وَ لَمْ يَرَ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا أَنَّ السَّماواتِ وَ الْأَرْضَ كانَتا رَتْقاً فَفَتَقْناهُما ...فَقَالَ لَهُ أَبُو جَعْفَرٍ ع فَلَعَلَّكَ تَزْعُمُ أَنَّهُمَا كَانَتَا رَتْقاً مُلْتَزِقَتَيْنِ مُلْتَصِقَتَيْنِ فَفُتِقَتْ إِحْدَاهُمَا مِنَ الْأُخْرَى فَقَالَ نَعَمْ فَقَالَ أَبُو جَعْفَرٍ ع اسْتَغْفِرْ رَبَّكَ

Comment: فَإِنَّ قَوْلَ اللَّهِ جَلَّ وَ عَزَّ كانَتا رَتْقاً يَقُولُ كَانَتِ السَّمَاءُ رَتْقاً لَا تُنْزِلُ الْمَطَرَ وَ كَانَتِ الْأَرْضُ رَتْقاً لَا تُنْبِتُ الْحَبَّ فَلَمَّا خَلَقَ اللَّهُ تَبَارَكَ وَ تَعَالَى الْخَلْقَ وَ بَثَّ فِيها مِنْ كُلِّ دَابَّةٍ* فَتَقَ السَّمَاءَ بِالْمَطَرِ وَ الْأَرْضَ بِنَبَاتِ الْحَبِّ فَقَالَ الشَّامِيُّ أَشْهَدُ أَنَّكَ مِنْ وُلْدِ الْأَنْبِيَاءِ وَ أَنَّ عِلْمَكَ عِلْمُهُم‏". Godspeed